# keeping sub menu open on hover and close sub menu on mouse move down or scrolling

Tags: jquery, menu

here is the code for menu.

```
(document).ready(function(){

$("#main-nav li a.main-link").hover(function(){
$("#main-nav li a.main-link").removeClass("active");                                                 
    $(this).addClass("active");                                      
    $("#sub-link-bar").animate({
        height: "40px"                     
    });
    $(".sub-links").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".sub-links").fadeIn();

});


   $("#main-nav").mouseleave(function(){    

    $("#main-nav li a.main-link").removeClass("active");                                                                                     
    $(".sub-links").fadeOut();
    $("#sub-link-bar").animate({
        height: "10px"                     
    });           
   });
});
```

HTML code

```
       <div id="sub-link-bar"> </div>

      <div id="wrap">

        <div class="roundfg">
  <ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a class="main-link" href="#">Home</a>
        <ul class="sub-links">
            <li><a class="main-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="main-link" href="#">Tutorials</a>
      <ul class="sub-links">
        <li><a href="#" >Design</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">HTML &amp; CSS</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#" >Other</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">PHP</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Ruby</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Site Builds</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tools &amp; Tips</a> </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-35"><a href="#">Wordpress</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li><a class="main-link" href="#">Videos</a>
        <ul class="sub-links">
        <li><a href="#">Screencasts</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="main-link" href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-links">

        </ul>
    </li>         
  </ul>
</div>
```

The sub menu hides when mouse leaves the main menu.

But if mouse is over sub menu,then also sub menu hides.

So I want to add functionality so that sub menu is hidden only if

1) mouse is moved down of main menu

2) if page is scrolled down

Please reply.
Thanks.

Comment: provide relevant HTML markup